# integrability of random variables w.r.t. Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider random variables $Z_t>0 \ \forall t \in [0,T] $, where $E[Z_T]=1$ and $Z_t=E[Z_T|F_t]$, where $F_t$ is the Brownian filtration  and $H$, which is integrable with respect to Brownian motion $W$, i.e. $\int_0^T |H(s)|^2 dt< \infty$ and it holds $Z_t = 1 + \int_0^t H(s) dW(s)$

Is there a way to show that $\frac{H}{Z}$ is $W-$integrable, i.e. $$\int_0^T \frac{|H(s)|^2}{|Z(s)|^2} ds < \infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $Z$ is continuous, the condition $Z_t > 0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ implies $\inf_{t \in [0,T]} Z_t = z > 0$.  Hence $$\int_0^T \frac{|H(s)|^2}{|Z(s)|^2} ds \le \frac{1}{z^2} \int_0^T |H(s)|^2 < \infty.$$

Comment: "Since $Z$ is continuous" some elaboration might be needed here.

Comment: It's given by $Z_t = 1 + \int_0^t H(s)dW(s)$ and integrals with respect to Brownian motion are continuous, or at least have continuous modifications which are typically used.

Comment: Sorry, being inattentive :)

Comment: @user6247850: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain what the difference is between martingale beeing continuous and only has contiuous modification?

Comment: @Alif A process $\tilde{Z}$ is a modification of $Z$ if $P(Z_t = \tilde{Z}_t) = 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: @user6247850: What does this mean here in detail. When I look at different processes at a given time they are always the same. Where can they differ from each other?

Comment: @Alif I was mistaken earlier: The definition of the stochastic integral with respect to Brownian motion includes that it is continuous.  To answer your question about where they can differ, let $Y$ be an exponential distributed random variable and $X_t := 1_{Y = t}$.  Then $P(X_t = 0) = P(Y \ne t) = 1$ for all $t$ so $X$ is a modification of the constant process $0$, but $X$ is not identically $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Do you mean Z is in general continuos?